# Search Bar incorrectly overlays in multiple view controller of navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller, uisearchbardelegate

I have a Search Bar working fine created like this for my UITableView Class shown below,

```
 class customTableViewController: UITableViewController,              UISearchResultsUpdating
{....
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = false
        controller.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.searchBarStyle = UISearchBarStyle(rawValue: 2)!

        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = controller.searchBar

        return controller
    })()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

It works fine, it's just that when I segue to another view controller, the image of the search bar remains drawn on my screen no matter what view controller I'm in.
When I try "searchBar.active = false", I get nil errors.

**What can I do so this searchBar is only drawn on this one tableViewController and nowhere else in my navigation?**

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Show a screenshot pls.

Comment: Tried to, not enough reputation.

Comment: What about calling resignFirstResponder on the search bar when you're segueing to a new view controller?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a bit of a work around,
In my prepareToSegue, I said:

```
   self.resultSearchController.searchBar.hidden = true
   self.resultSearchController.view.endEditing(true)
```

That's it, and in the destinationViewController I wrote the code below to recognize that its returning to the originalViewController and to redraw the bar.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    ....
    resultSearchController.searchBar.hidden = false
}
```